# Recursively adding a ChildNode to a Parent Node

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, treenode

I have a problem that I cannot seem to solve.

I am building a TreeView dynamically and I have an ordered list. I want the TreeView to build in such a way:

> Node1
>
> _Node2
>
> __ Node3
>
> __ _Node..N

My code is as follows:

> ```
>         TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < EmployeesReportingLine.Count; i++ )
>         {
>             Employee ep = EmployeesReportingLine[i];
>
>             while (tn.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
>                 tn = tn.ChildNodes[0];
>
>             TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(ep.FullName);
>             if (i > 0)
>                 tn.ChildNodes.Add(temp);
>             else
>                 tn = temp;
>         }
>
>         TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
> ```

I have made several other attempts at using recursive functions but the snippet above was my best attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void addNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, TreeNode newnode) {
        if (nodes.Count == 0) nodes.Add(newnode);
        else addNode(nodes[0].Nodes, newnode);
    }
```

Or:

```
    private void addNode2(TreeNode start, TreeNode newnode) {
        if (start.Nodes.Count == 0) start.Nodes.Add(newnode);
        else addNode2(start.Nodes[0], newnode);
    }
```